# Spring XML Initialization Order

Tags: xml, spring, configuration, autowired

Can someone explain the order of initialization for beans in a Spring xml configuration file?  It appears to be order dependent in certain circumstances but I was unable to find any documentation indicating this.  When using a single configuration file, bean order appears to be independent.  However, if overriding a bean in a parent configuration, the order can be significant.  I need to do additional testing to confirm exactly what circumstances cause this to fail.  I am using Spring 3.0.5 and using a configuration file to override beans in my production code with mocked implementations.  The beans are autowired into a service and mocked objects are why the override is needed. Any insight on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Order is sometimes significant, I can think of these circumstances:

1. Beans defined later with the exact same name override the beans defined earlier - so if you have mocks for some of the beans, just define it after the core application beans have been loaded up.
2. BeanFactoryPostProcessors and BeanPostProcessors are processed based on their definition position or based on an `order` property if present.
3. AOP advices are executed based on the `order` property.

Your condition seems to be covered by the 1st point, but I just specified others for completeness, there are definitely more though which other SO users can add on.

Comment: My mocked beans in the child context are overriding beans with the same name in the parent context. The child context imports the parent. I assumed this meant the parent context was initialized, then the child context but this does not seem to be the case. Can you clarify how to ensure one context file is fully loaded before the overrides?

Comment: Say if you have a `parent-context.xml` file with bean1 - `<bean name="bean1".../>` now in your child context you must done this: `<import resource="parent-context.xml"> <bean name="bean1" class="mock"/>` , in this case since your `bean1` in child context is defined after the ones from the import of your parent, the one's in child will take effect, instead if you do `<bean name="bean1" class="mock"/><import resource="parent-context.xml"/>`, so now the parent context is imported after the child beans are defined, so the parent bean will take effect